# multiple timestamps in one program execution

Tags: java, timestamp

Need help!
I am not able to get multiple timestamps in one execution,
basically i am running a test suite , and i am using ordernumbers as the current timestamp in hhmmss,
But when first time timestamp is taken, it has the same value throughout the execution, i want changing current values, during the execution.

code used :

```
static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss");
static Date date = new Date();
public static String ordernum = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always reusing the same `Date` object. You need to create a `new Date()` every time you need a new timestamp.

**Update**

Took another look at your question: using a second-precision timestamp is probably not the best guarantee for uniqueness, especially in test execution.

Why not do:

```
String ordernum = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Or:

```
String ordernum = "" + System.nanoTime();
```

Comment: no i have tried creating the date object twice, i still get the same timestamp

Comment: Impossible unless you've created both in the same millisecond. Or, in case you're rounding down to seconds, in the same second.

Comment: @XtremeCore show us how did you create it

Comment: Yeah , thanks, u were right, the problem was that i had a static date object overriding it.